# matlab unique identifier based on number

Tags: java, matlab, hash, hash-function

I'm looking for a unique identifier based on a float number in matlab, so hash functions came to mind. Does Matlab (our its less documented Java part, or even (windows) system commands) offer any possibilities for *any* hash function, such as MD5?

```
uniquehash=hash(5);
uniquehash=hash('asdf');
```

related: [datahash script](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash) 
Unique Identifier from java that may be of use: `char(java.util.UUID.randomUUID)`

As far as I've seen, this is not a duplicate as I need a unique identifier based on a float number. however let me know if it is...

Comment: A unique identifier _of what_? Anyway, [this](http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash) may be helpful (user-contributed function)

Comment: @LuisMendo: ...of a row in a 2D-matrix

Comment: @user2305193: [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197315/52738) makes a very clear argument for just using the double-precision value as the unique identifier. It's not clear what format you may want the identifier in, so I just wanted to make you aware of the [`num2hex`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2hex.html) function for converting a double value to a hexadecimal string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need a unique identifier based on a float number.

Assuming that you are talking about a 64-bit floating point number, that means there can only be 2^64 (max) possible unique identifiers.  You may as well either use the number itself as the identifier.

Using a crypto hash like MD5, SHA1, SHA2 etc doesn't make the number any more unique.  At the end of the day, the 2^64 possible floating point numbers map to 2^64 possible hashes.  Most of the 2^128 (or whatever) theoretically possible hashes simply cannot be generated.

(If you are talking about 32 bit floats, substitute 2^32 for 2^64!)

Comment: that is elegantly stated and absolutely true, I did not think this through enough. The reasoning behind it was, to dynamically fill a matrix, then keep track of the rows using a unique identifier. However if you use a float number to do that, the hash function is obsolete (i.e. we agree), if that is not the case, then `char(java.util.UUID.randomUUID)` can be used to create unique identifiers